# Conversion from type string to double is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have some very simple vb.net code and get this error message. What I'm trying to do is check if btn3 is pressed and if tbAantalIslands is higher or lower than 2 and change the color of the button accordingly.

I have searched the internet a bit and did find a fix, if I give tbAantalIslands a value it works. But my program requires the user to fill in the value himself, but if I leave it blank it gives this error.

here is my code:

```
        'it works when i give tbAantalIslands.Text a value, but thats not what I want to do

        ' tbAantalIslands.Text = 1

        If tbAantalIslands.Text > 2 Then

            If iBtnClickCheck > 0 Then
                btn3.BackColor = Color.Red

            End If

        ElseIf tbAantalIslands.Text < 2 Then
            If iBtnClickCheck > 0 Then
                btn3.BackColor = Color.Green

            End If

        End If
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you do realise that you're not doing anything if the value is exactly 2, right?

Comment: @jmcilhinney 
yeah i realised that, i changed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to validate and convert is to use the appropriate `TryParse` method:

```vb
Dim aantalIslands As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(tbAantalIslands.Text, aantalIslands) Then
    If aantalIslands > 2 Then
        '...
    ElseIf aantalIslands < 2 Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

EDIT:

Based on recent comments, it seems like you should be adjusting the `If` statement like so:

```vb
Dim aantalIslands As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(tbAantalIslands.Text, aantalIslands) Then
    If aantalIslands > 2 Then
        '...
    Else
        '...
    End If
End If
```

Actually, given what you're doing, if would be better to make the whole thing more succinct:

```vb
Dim aantalIslands As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(tbAantalIslands.Text, aantalIslands) AndAlso
   iBtnClickCheck > 0 Then
    btn3.BackColor = If(aantalIslands > 2, Color.Red, Color.Green)
End If
```

Comment: so this is basically a better way to do the same thing as what the other user has commented, right?

Comment: the only thing that doesn't work with this method, is the else condition. it doesn't change the color of the button when aantalIslands is less then or equal to 2

Comment: The code I posted will work for values less than 2, assuming you used what I posted properly. Of course it won't do anything if the value is equal to 2 though. Neither does the code you posted originally, which is exactly why I commented on that against the question. If you want to do one thing for values great than 2 and another thing otherwise, you should have an `ElseIf` to begin with. You should just have an `Else` in that case, so you're only testing one condition. I just followed the cue from your original code. If that's wrong, don't blame me.

Comment: alright, I just tested with both the is smaller than and equal to thingy and that didn't work. I also tested it with just an Else, didn't do anything either. I'm pretty sure I got the code correctly, since I just copy pasted it from yours and changed it so it should work. Also I'm not blaming you for anything, I'm just stating what happened.

wrote this before you updated your code, will test that now.

Comment: Your most recent code did work. It's also a lot more compact than what I had or what others suggested, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have Option Strict Off, and the compiler is adding an implicit conversion from string to double on `tbAantalIslands.Text > 2`.  An implicit conversion doesn’t do any validation or error checking, and it is failing when the value is not a double.

I would suggest turning Option Strict On, in order to find these sorts of issues, and do an explicit conversion with input validation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
        If IsNumeric(tbAantalIslands.Text) AndAlso Integer.Parse(tbAantalIslands.Text) > 2 Then
            If iBtnClickCheck > 0 Then btn3.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf IsNumeric(tbAantalIslands.Text) AndAlso Integer.Parse(tbAantalIslands.Text) < 2 Then
            If iBtnClickCheck > 0 Then btn3.BackColor = Color.Green
        End If
```

Comment: Don't use `IsNumeric` at all but especially not when you want the numeric result. `IsNumeric` calls `Double.TryParse` internally - the latter was written specifically for the former, so you should call it yourself. As it stands, you're parsing the same text up to four times instead of just once.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj
Thank you so much, this works like a charm for now. I did change some of the parameters, to accomodate for multiple buttons and it works too. Only downside I have now is that I have to copy/paste the codes for each button to make it work. the only difference in the code is the iBtnClickCheck, so the program knows which button has been pressed, it gives the variable a value that stands for one of the buttons so it changes the color of the correct button.

Comment: @jmcilhinney "IsNumeric calls Double.TryParse internally" do you have any link about this, I'm courious!!!

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj 
i figured out what to do instead of just copy and pasting the code for all the buttons, I just created a function and put the button handler code in there and called for that function in each button handler sub. 

thanks again for helping me, appreciate it.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj The source code of the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace isn't publicly available but you can use a decompiler to peek inside it. You'll find that `IsNumeric` does a lot more than `Double.TryParse` (which is actually a good reason _not_ to use it unless you know exactly what you're doing), but yes it does use `Double.TryParse` internally. See [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/D2TFiYR.png). Additionally, checking `IsNumeric` (or even `Double.TryParse`) and then calling _Integer_.Parse is never a good idea, for obvious reasons.

Comment: By the way, the behavior of `IsNumeric` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric?view=net-5.0#remarks) if you don't care about the actual implementation.

Comment: @41686d6564 There is several methods that if someone go inside (in C engine) are not properly used is some circumstances as calls other methods also present in the current framework.
But in a every day programming the fluency is first thing we all uses.

Comment: I can't recall where it was but, very early on in the .NET days, I read that the original implementation of `IsNumeric` was too slow because it relied on an exception being thrown on invalid data. That source said that `Double.TryParse` was written specifically to speed up `IsNumeric`, which is why that's the only `TryParse` method that originally existed. It was such a good idea that they added `TryParse` methods for all other appropriate data types too. Note that `IsNumeric` has been implemented specifically to behave the same as `IsNumeric` in VB6. Don't use VB6 holdovers if possible.

Comment: *"the fluency is first thing"*. Using `TryParse` is no less "fluent" and, when you need the result, is more "fluent", so there really isn't a good argument for using `IsNumeric`, especially once you are aware that it's a tangled mess of unnecessary stuff. The only reason to use it is if you're upgrading VB6 code and you want to make sure that it behaves exactly the same way.